# How to make width of dropwdown items Flexible?

Tags: css, xhtml

http://www.lwis.net/free-css-drop-down-menu/dropdown.simple.horizontal.html

in this sample width of dropdown is fixed

```
ul.dropdown ul {
margin-top:1px;
width:150px;}
```

I need width of drop-down dependable of Character inside `<a>` without breaking in 2 line

width should depend on text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following two additional style declarations in Firebug gave me the results you're asking for.

```
ul.dropdown ul
{ width: auto; }

ul.dropdown ul li
{ white-space: nowrap; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Set a min / max width, or, not set a width at all (and add some padding)?

```
min-width{10px;}
max-width{15px;}
```

I know min/max-width will not be supported in IE7 or below

Answer (score 1):

Block level elements don't collapse down to the width of the contents. You might be able to get around this with inline-block, but that could get tricky.

Might be best to use javascript to calculate the width based on the widest LI. Let it load sans a specific width, have javascript kick in looping through each `<a>` in each `<li>` to find the widest, and then set the UL to that specific width.